# mysql command not found in mac from terminal

Tags: mysql, macos, bash, terminal

I just installed mysql from this [site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql), and was successful with that. But when i tried to open with command `mysql -u root -ppassword` on terminal it is showing `-bash: mysql: command not found`

But when i tried it like below i can able to login successfully in to mysql.

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -ppassword
```

So what i should i make to use just `mysql` instead of `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`.
(By the way i am new to Mac)

Answer (score 1):

You can update your .profile or .bashrc file to include the directory /usr/local/mysql/bin to your PATH variable.  In addition you can create a symbolic link to a location already in your PATH variable.

Comment: how to add that with export command ?, adding in to eigther of file is ok ?

Comment: export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH  it is better to add it to the bashrc file.  I think .profile may be used for other shells.

Comment: I already have PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH how should I added?

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following in terminal:

Type cd

drag the path on to the terminal where the dmg exists

Type /usr/LOCAL/mysql/BIN/mysql -h host -u user -p

(host=hostname user=username to login to access database)

On giving valid credentials, you will be prompted for password

On giving valid password,it will be displayed with Welcome to mysql monitor and soon.. with the below prompt

mysql>